# c# linq group by into view models

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My matrices table looks like this

[image]

Using linq I want the results to bind to my view models below. A matricesView will be the Y coordinate and have a list of (matrix) all the X coordinate's values.

```
public class MatricesView
{
    public List<MatrixView> Matrix { get; set; }
    public MatricesView()
    {
        Matrix = new List<MatrixView>();
    }
}
public class MatrixView
{
    public string Value { get; set;}
}
```

I am currently querying as is and then looping to create my view models.

```
int previousY = 0;
            MatricesView matrice = new MatricesView();
            foreach(var matrix in table.Matrices)
            {
                if (previousY != matrix.Y)
                {
                    matrice = new MatricesView();
                    Matrices.Add(matrice);
                    previousY = matrix.Y;
                }
                matrice.Matrix.Add(new MatrixView() { Value = matrix.Value == "****" ? " " : matrix.Value});
            }
```

Is it possible to do this logic directly with linq when querying my database:

```
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        return context.Tables
                .Where(predicate)
                .Select(t => new TableViewModel()
                {
                    Name = t.Name,
                    Question = t.Question,
                    Base = t.Base,
                    Categories = t.Categories.Select(category => new CategoryView() { Name = category.Name, ColSpan = category.ColSpan }).ToList(),
                    Demographics = t.Demographics.Select(demographic => new DemographicView() { Name = demographic.Value }).ToList(),
                    Trailers = t.Trailers.Select(trailer => new TrailerView() { Name = trailer.Value }).ToList(),
                    Matrices = .....?
                }).ToList();
    }
```

EDIT:

The solution was:

```
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        return context.Tables
                .Where(predicate)
                .Select(t => new TableViewModel()
                {
                    Name = t.Name,
                    Question = t.Question,
                    Base = t.Base,
                    Categories = t.Categories.Select(category => new CategoryView() { Name = category.Name, ColSpan = category.ColSpan }).ToList(),
                    Demographics = t.Demographics.Select(demographic => new DemographicView() { Name = demographic.Value }).ToList(),
                    Trailers = t.Trailers.Select(trailer => new TrailerView() { Name = trailer.Value }).ToList(),
                    Matrices = t.Matrices.GroupBy(x => x.Y).Select(x => new MatricesView { Matrix = x.Select(y => new MatrixView(){ Value = y.Value}).ToList() }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: The short answer is yes, but can you explain the problems that you are having when you attempt to do this?

Comment: This works but I need to query my matrices table then loop all matrices and create a matrices viewmodel. I want to do it all in my context.Tables query using linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do a group by. The end result would look something like this:

```
return context.Tables
    .Where(predicate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Y)
    .Select(t => new TableViewModel()
    {
        Name = t.FirstOrDefault().Name,
        Question = t.FirstOrDefault().Question,
        Base = t.FirstOrDefault().Base,
        Categories = t.FirstOrDefault().Categories.Select(category => new CategoryView() { Name = category.Name, ColSpan = category.ColSpan }).ToList(),
        Demographics = t.FirstOrDefault().Demographics.Select(demographic => new DemographicView() { Name = demographic.Value }).ToList(),
        Trailers = t.FirstOrDefault().Trailers.Select(trailer => new TrailerView() { Name = trailer.Value }).ToList(),
        Matrices = new MatrixView() 
        { 
            Matrix = t.Select(x => new MatrixView { Value = x.Value == "****" ? " " : x.Value }).ToList() 
        }
    }).ToList();
```

**Edit:** Just for completeness sake, here's what Mike used in the final result:

```
...
Matrices = t.Matrices.GroupBy(x => x.Y).Select(x => new MatricesView 
{ 
    Matrix = x.Select(y => new MatrixView(){ Value = y.Value}).ToList() 
}).ToList()
```

Comment: My tables have a list of matrices. If I put group by there it will group by tables. I need to group by matrices.

Comment: Here was my solution. I'll mark you as correct answer because you opened by brain. 

Matrices = t.Matrices.GroupBy(x => x.Y).Select(x => new MatricesView { Matrix = x.Select(y => new MatrixView(){ Value = y.Value}).ToList() }).ToList()